# Add title to readmore button in tagged articles using joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm new to joomla and I have a problem in adding title of articles in read more button using TAG ITEMS.

I have two articles like this:

**Lorem Ipsum**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis elit augue. Aliquam mattis sem sed ligula mattis faucibus. Donec vitae pretium sem. Vivamus ipsum enim...

Read More

**Dolor Sit amet**

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas purus ex, ultrices eget ante ac, tempor suscipit nunc. Etiam viverra dolor id...

Read More

=========================================================================

What i want to do is add the title of each article to the readmore button, so it would look like this:

**Lorem Ipsum**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis elit augue. Aliquam mattis sem sed ligula mattis faucibus. Donec vitae pretium sem. Vivamus ipsum enim...

Read More: Lorem Ipsum

**Dolor sit amet**

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas purus ex, ultrices eget ante ac, tempor suscipit nunc. Etiam viverra dolor id...

Read More: Dolor sit amet

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Content -> Articles -> Options, set "Show Title with Read More" = "Show".

Comment: I tried it, and it seems it only affect on articles not tagged articles or tag items.

Comment: I tried to go to Global Configuration -> Tags and it seems there's no option in setting "Show Title with Read More" just like in articles.